# C++: Is 2 + x + 1 the same as 3 + x?

Tags: c++, google-chrome

This following snippet of code from the Chromium source caught my eye (see line 155 [here](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/ui/webui/print_preview/print_preview_ui.cc)):

```
std::string PrintPreviewUI::GetPrintPreviewUIAddress() const {
  // Store the PrintPreviewUIAddress as a string.
  // "0x" + deadc0de + '\0' = 2 + 2 * sizeof(this) + 1;
  char preview_ui_addr[2 + (2 * sizeof(this)) + 1];
  base::snprintf(preview_ui_addr, sizeof(preview_ui_addr), "%p", this);
  return preview_ui_addr;
}
```

Doesn't `2 + (2 * sizeof(this)) + 1` evaluate to `3 + 2 * sizeof(this)`? Why did the authors choose to write the expression this way?

Comment: Did you not see the comment in the line above?

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I guess I don't understand it!

Comment: It shows the reasoning behind the expression so you don't have to wonder about the magic `3` in the alternative you suggest.

Comment: Of course, you should really avoid all of the above. The function seems to be equivalent to: `std::ostringstream buf; buf << (void *)this; return buf.str();` or (C++11): `return std::to_string((void *)this);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it does evaluate the same way.

Presumably the authors wrote it that way to make it clearer how their array was laid out -- i.e. that it contained 2 bytes for one thing, then 2 pointers, and then 1 more byte after that.   (Actually I'm not sure why they chose to use the sizeof() operator in this case, since the length of a string representation of a pointer isn't the same as the pointer's in-memory width)

The compiler will optimize away the math at compile time, so performance isn't effected; it's just to keep other programmers from having to figure out where the 3 came from.

Comment: Note: `sizeof(this)` is not the same as `sizeof(*this)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the same, assuming that all of the types are integral and not floating-point, like they are in this case (for floating-point, the result will *usually* be the same, but there are some weird edge cases involving when things are rounded that can surprise you).

The authors probably chose to write it that way for clarity: they're storing a specific string in the buffer which is constructed by taking two bytes, adding some more data, and then adding one more byte.  Writing it this way allows the code reader to easily double-check that the calculated size indeed matches up with the amount of data being written by matching up the pieces one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

possibly for readability.  Whoever wrote it is trying to express that 2 and 1 are two different pieces of information instead of just having 3 and not knowing what makes it up

Answer (score 0):

This will make no difference to the assembly code generated during the translation stage of the compilation process.

The only real reason I can think of for the author to write the code this way might be for readability reasons - perhaps the logic is clearer this way, than if the author had used "algebraic simplification" before implementing this logic in code.

On a purely mathematical note regarding the title of the post - yes 2 + x + 1 is indeed equal to x + 3.  However, unlike in computer programming, it is never valid in mathematics (at least arithmetic/algebra) to say that x = x + 1 :-)